# Problems of using the Socket.IO-Client-Swift in objc project

Tags: ios, objective-c, socket.io

I import the [Socket.IO-Client-Swift](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-swift) to my obj-c project and try to use it like

`#import "socketio-Swift.h"`

(socketio is the project name)

and then

```
SocketIOClient *client = [[SocketIOClient alloc] initWithSocketURL:@"xxx" options:nil];
[client on:@"1" callback:<#^(NSArray *, void (^)(NSArray *))callback#>];
```

but I don't quite understand the block,how should I fill the block?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The socket.io guys have updated how to use this in objc on their [github](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-swift)

```
SocketIOClient* socket = [[SocketIOClient alloc] initWithSocketURL:@"localhost:8080" options:nil];

[socket on: @"connect" callback: ^(NSArray* data, void (^ack)(NSArray*)) {
    NSLog(@"connected");
    [socket emitObjc:@"echo" withItems:@[@"echo test"]];
    [socket emitWithAckObjc:@"ackack" withItems:@[@1]](10, ^(NSArray* data) {
        NSLog(@"Got ack");
    });
}];

[socket connect];
```

Comment: Can you please share for latest swift 5 library. because there are no method `[[SocketIOClient alloc] initWithSocketURL....`

Answer (score 0):

It should looks like:

```
[client on:@"something" callback:^(NSArray *array, void (^action)(NSArray *actionArr)) {
    /*
     Do something
     */
    NSArray * newArr;
    action(newArr);
}];
```